# Finding the class number of $K$

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Consider the following: we have a square-free, positive, composite integer $d$ such that $-d\equiv 2\text{ or }3\bmod4$, $p$ is a prime divisor of $d$, and $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-d})$.

My goal is to do the following:

> Show that $K$ has no element of norm $\pm p$, hence or otherwise, by considering the prime factorisation of $\langle p \rangle$, prove that the class number of $K$ is even.

First of all, this is my attempt at showing that no element has norm $p$:

Suppose $\alpha=x+y\sqrt{-d}$ is an element of $K$, and write $d=cp$, $c\geqslant2$. Then  equation $\operatorname{N}_{K/\mathbb Q}(\alpha)=\pm p$ has no solutions since otherwise
           $$x^2+p(cy^2\pm1)=0,$$
           which is impossible unless $x=1$ and $y=0$ (in which case $x^2=\pm p$, also impossible), since  $$|x^2+p(cy^2\pm1)|\geqslant |x^2+p(2y^2\pm1)| > 0,$$
           where the inequality follows easily by considering cases of $x,y$ being equal to/different from zero separately.

(I'm not sure if this is the easiest way to go about this)

Next, applying Dedekind-Kummer, the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{-d}$ over $\mathbb Z$ is $x^2+d^2=x^2+c^2p^2\equiv x^2\bmod p$. Thus $\langle p\rangle = \langle p, -d\rangle=\langle p \rangle$, and in particular, $\langle p \rangle$ is prime.

How does this help me show the class number is even?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $p$ ramifies, so you cannot apply Dedekind Kummer. But $p$ ramifying implies that $\langle p \rangle=\mathfrak p^2$ for some prime ideal $\mathfrak p$. This cannot be a principal ideal, because if it were, then its generator would have norm $p$. Therefore $\mathfrak p$ is an element of the class group having order 2.